# JSON value validation

Tags: node.js, json, validation

I am using JSON schema for setting body for post request in node.js application

```
let ProductSchema = new Schema({
    sku: {type: String, required: true},
    ean: {type: Number, required: true},
    mpn: {type: Number, required: true},
});
```

to validate JSON body for a POST request, but the problem that I have is that only one of 3 values is required, so if the user in POST request populate JSON as a

```
{
    "sku": "test",
}
```

without ean or mpn, it should still be valid.

I am not sure how to start with this, so does someone have some hint where to look for?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question here. You have marked three values as required and now you're wondering how you can mark two of them as not required?

Answer (score 1):

You should use wonderful module: joi

For allowing only one of three params, i.e. exactly one of param must be present.
Lets say you have five fields in your schema, and you want one out of (field1, field2, field3) must be present.

```
Joi.object({
  field1: Joi.string(),
  field2: Joi.string(),
  field3: Joi.string(),
  field4: Joi.string(),
  field5: Joi.string(),
}).xor('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

Now, it will allow only one of these three fields.

See: [Schema validation with Joi](https://www.gyanblog.com/gyan/nodejs-npm-object-schema-validation-with-joi/)